# Overloading a method with Object as parameter type

Tags: vb.net, object, inheritance, overloading

I'm trying to figure out this weird behavior.  I have a base class (A) with an overloaded method called "M": one for integers, and one for floats (single on VB.NET).

On the other hand, I have a second class (B) that inherits from A, and it overloads method M in two ways: one for data type double, and one for object data type.

The problem is: I expect the methods to use each function for its data type, but for some strange reason, the method with Object data type takes all the calls. Why is that happening?

I expected the output of this program to be `15`, but instead, it's `4`.

Here's the code (VB.NET):

```
Module Module1

Public Class A

    Public Function M(ByVal a As Integer) As Integer
        Return 8
    End Function

    Public Function M(ByVal a As Single) As Integer
        Return 4
    End Function

End Class

Public Class B
    Inherits A

    Public Overloads Function M(ByVal a As Double) As Integer
        Return 2
    End Function

    Public Overloads Function M(ByVal a As Object) As Integer
        Return 1
    End Function

End Class


Sub Main()

    Dim a0 As Double = 1
    Dim a1 As Single = 2
    Dim a2 As Integer = 4
    Dim a3 As Object = 8

    Dim arre(4)

    arre(0) = a0
    arre(1) = a1
    arre(2) = a2
    arre(3) = a3

    Dim b As New B

    Dim suma% = 0

    For i = 0 To 3
        suma += b.M(arre(i))
    Next i

    Console.WriteLine(suma)

    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Sleep(2000)
End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: What happens if you do:  `Dim var as Double =7` : `b.M(var)` ?

Comment: In that case, it uses the "Double" method. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it calls the overload that takes an `Object` is because your array is of type `Object`.

```
' original code
Dim arre(4)

arre(0) = a0
arre(1) = a1
arre(2) = a2
arre(3) = a3

' verbose version
Dim arre(4) As Object

arre(0) = DirectCast(a0, Object)
arre(1) = DirectCast(a1, Object)
arre(2) = DirectCast(a2, Object)
arre(3) = DirectCast(a3, Object)
```

Look up "boxing" and "unboxing" in .NET, there are tons of good articles that explain this in more detail.

Comment: It's weird, because the debugger says that arre(0) is of type double, but calls "object" type instead.
I tried calling function M with a "Double" variable, and it went to the "Double" function, so your explanation makes sense. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The actual value in `arre(0)` is still of type `Double`, but it's "boxed" as (converted to) `Object`. This is only made possible because `Double` inherits from `Object` (and so does everything else, by the way).

Answer (score 0):

The Object overload is being called in your example every time because you are declaring the array as a Object array. (`Option Strict` will force you to put `As Object` after it, but that doesn't change things.) It doesn't matter what type you put inside the array because the values are getting "boxed" into Objects

Consider the following, simplified to demonstrate what is happening
(There is no need for your custom classes or inheritance to demonstrate what you saw)

```
Module Module1

Public Function M(ByVal a As Integer) As Integer
    Return 8
End Function

Public Function M(ByVal a As Object) As Integer
    Return 1
End Function

Sub Main()
    Dim a0 As Integer = 0
    Dim a1 As Object = 0
    Dim arre(1)
    arre(0) = a0
    arre(1) = a1

    Console.WriteLine(M(arre(0)))
    ' 1, arre() is implicitly typed as an array of Objects
    ' so the Object overload will be called

    Console.WriteLine(M(arre(1)))
    ' 1, see above

    Console.WriteLine(M(DirectCast(arre(0), Integer)))
    ' 8, explicit cast to an Integer

    Console.WriteLine(M(DirectCast(arre(1), Integer)))
    ' 8, see above

    Console.WriteLine(M(a0))
    ' 8, a0 declared explicitly as an Integer

    Console.WriteLine(M(a1))
    ' 1, a1 declared explicitly as an Object

    Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Excellent, that totally makes sense.  Unfortunately, I can only check one answer as "my accepted answer", and another person gave me a similar answer first. But thanks a lot!!! Awesome explanation.